# why is it $\frac{-6+5 }{-1+0}$ at the end instead of $0$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

The question is $\lim_{x \to 2^+} \frac{[\![1-3x]\!]+[\![3x-1]\!]}{sign(4-x^2)+|x-2|}=?$

The solution provided is

\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 2^+} \frac{[\![1-3x]\!]+[\![3x-1]\!]}{sign(4-x^2)+|x-2|} &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{[\![1-3(2+h)]\!]+[\![3(2+h)-1]\!]}{sign(4-(2+h)^2)+|2+h-2|} \\
&=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{[\![-5-3h]\!]+[\![5+3h]\!]}{sign(-4h-h^2)+|h|}\\
&=\frac{-6+5}{-1+0} = \frac{-1}{-1}=1
\end{align}

I can't understand why it is $\frac{-6+5}{-1+0}$ at the end instead of $0$.

Comment: Does the [x] notation refer to the floor function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two comments:

- It seems that $[\![ .]\!]$ means floor function.
- The solution shouldn't have been replacing $x \to 2^+$ with $h \to 0$, instead, it should have been $h\to 0^+$.

If $h$ is positive but sufficiently small, then $-6\le -5-3h<-5$, by taking the floor function, we have $[\![ -5-3h]\!]=-6.$